# Wordpress - How to create a fav posts feature

Tags: wordpress

I want my users to be able to mark posts as favorite. I tried the wp-favorite-posts plugin, but it doesn't work. I mark posts as favorites and after refreshing the page it's all gone. Furthermore, if I put {{wp-favorite-posts}} to a page, it just shows the text.
So I want to create my own solution, but don't really know how. I have never edited the WP database, but I have plenty of PHP mySQL experience.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction ?

Comment: What I would do is make a table called 'fav_posts' to connect user ID's with post ID, so it would have 2 rows. 
I suppose I could figure out adding posts. There would be a link with the current user ID and post ID somewhere in it. The link would trigger an ajax event which would create the new DB record or delete it if 'unfavorite' was clicked.
Now the harder part would be getting the posts, somehow combining the new table with the WP query. 
I could create an empty page, and in page.php and add a condition to check if the current page is the favs page. But how do I output only the fav posts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use post_meta. You can store the "favourite" aspect as a custom field attached to each post. You don't need to manually edit the database (i.e. via mySQL).

When you want to show the favourited posts, run a custom query that only shows posts with the specific custom field that you've specified.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it. Here's the code, if anyone's interested: https://github.com/marian-cerny/mc-ajax-favorite-posts. Maybe I'll post it to WP Plugins repo, if I have some free time.